# Redirect with Env-variable at the beginning

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect to a file with env-variable at the beginning, like:

```
RewriteRule (.*) %{ENV:BASE}tmp.php?tmp=%{ENV:BASE} [L,QSA]
```

The result will be a Internal Error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop rewriting after it has been rewritten once. Use this code:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) %{ENV:BASE}tmp.php?tmp=%{ENV:BASE} [L,QSA]
```